# Powershell AD results to csv Apple School Manager

Tags: powershell

I'm at a loss and wondering if someone might be smart and kind enough to help me across the finish line.

I'm pulling information from a csv which is then searching our AD and outputting the relevant information into a new csv.

I'm almost there however I need to bundle the groups in col A and in B have them run in a single row.

for example

```
B0000180    A00000009
B0000180    A00000002
B0000180    A00000008
M0000140    A00000001
M0001040    A00000009
M0000140    A00000005
M0000140    A00000009
MD000049    A00000008
MD000049    A00000007
MD000049    A00000002
MD000049    A00000000
MDIA1069    A00000007
MDIA1069    A00000005
MDIA1140    A00000005
MDIA1140    A00000062
MDIA1140    A00000069
M1111144    A00000095
M2222260    A00000042
M2222260    A00000086
```

what I would like to see is

```
B0000180    A00000009 A00000002 A00000008
M0000140    A00000001 A00000009 A00000005 A00000009
MD000049    A00000008 A00000007 A00000002 A00000000
MDIA1069    A00000007 A00000005
MDIA1140    A00000005 A00000062 A00000069
M1111144    A00000095
M2222260    A00000042 A00000086
```

The script I have so far is

```
$csv = import-csv C:\ASM\IN\asm-data.csv 
$csv | foreach-object {
    $Class = $_.class_id
    $Instructor = $_.instructor
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Class$Instructor -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties employeeID | Select-Object @{n=”class_id”;e={$class}}, employeeID | Export-CSV C:\ASM\OUT\classes.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With or without the starting example csv data containing [first row] column headers (e.g.`instructor, class_id`), you can formulate the preferred output using the below PowerShell logic.

> **Note:** If the Csv file does indeed already contain the column header values, then the first line will be `$csv = Import-Csv "C:\ASM\IN\asm-data.csv"` omitting the `-Header Instructor, Class_Id`
> entirely.

1. Define the column header values using `-Header Instructor, Class_Id`
   with the `Import-Csv` command so it can `Group-Object` by
   `Instructor` and use `[PSCustomObject]` with a hashtable.
2. The `Instructor` custom data objects will use `($_.group).'Instructor' | Select-Object -Unique` so no duplicates instructors are listed.
3. The `Class` custom data objects will `-join` the `Class_Id` values with each other using a space as the separator (i.e. `'Class' = ($_.group).'Class_Id' -join " "`)

### PowerShell

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\ASM\IN\asm-data.csv" -Header Instructor, Class_Id;
$groups = $csv | Group-Object Instructor;
$data = $groups | % {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Instructor' = ($_.group).'Instructor' | Select-Object -Unique;
        'Class' = ($_.group).'Class_Id' -join " ";
    };
};
$data;
### $data | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders; ## use this to select data with no header columns
```

**Output**

```
Instructor Class                                  
---------- -----                                  
B0000180   A00000009 A00000002 A00000008          
M0000140   A00000001 A00000005 A00000009          
M0001040   A00000009                              
MD000049   A00000008 A00000007 A00000002 A00000000
MDIA1069   A00000007 A00000005                    
MDIA1140   A00000005 A00000062 A00000069          
M1111144   A00000095                              
M2222260   A00000042 A00000086
```

### PowerShell (new variation)

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\ASM\IN\asm-data.csv" -Header Instructor, Class_Id;
$groups = $csv | Group-Object Instructor;
$data = $groups | % {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Instructor' = ($_.group).'Instructor' | Select-Object -Unique;
        'Class1' = ($_.group)[0].'Class_Id' -join ",";
        'Class2' = ($_.group)[1].'Class_Id' -join ",";
        'Class3' = ($_.group)[2].'Class_Id' -join ",";
        'Class4' = ($_.group)[3].'Class_Id' -join ",";
        'Class5' = ($_.group)[4].'Class_Id' -join ",";
    };
};
$tempCSV = "$Env:TEMP\~tempcsv.csv";
$data | Export-Csv $tempCSV -NoTypeInformation -Force;
$data = Import-Csv $tempCSV | FT;
$data;
```

**Output**

```
Instructor Class1    Class2    Class3    Class4    Class5
---------- ------    ------    ------    ------    ------
B0000180   A00000009 A00000002 A00000008                 
M0000140   A00000001 A00000005 A00000009                 
M0001040   A00000009                                     
MD000049   A00000008 A00000007 A00000002 A00000000       
MDIA1069   A00000007 A00000005                           
MDIA1140   A00000005 A00000062 A00000069                 
M1111144   A00000095                                     
M2222260   A00000042 A00000086
```

---

## Supporting Resources

- [Import-Csv](https://ss64.com/ps/import-csv.html)

  > `-Header string[]`
  >
  > An alternate column header row for the imported file. The column
  > header determines the names of the properties of the object created.
  >
  > Enter a comma-separated list of the column headers.
- [Combine duplicate rows data into an array from csv](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2284803-combine-duplicate-rows-data-into-an-array-from-csv)
- [Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2)
- [Use Hash Tables in PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-hash-tables.html)
- [Group-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/group-object.html)

  > Group objects that contain the same value.
- [Select-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)

  > `-Unique`
  >
  > Select unique objects only, (identical properties and values)

Comment: @Luke .... This is a starting point for you to get your data ironed out per the example you provided. I'd likely need more detail from you to better integrate in with the AD commands, but that's just trivial since I work with AD and PowerShell on a daily basis. In any event, per my interpretation of what you provided, I think this will help you reach your ultimate goal, but let me know what further I can do to help you get this 100% fully resolved if anything further is need, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for this, combining what I previously had to get results from AD I was able to see the data they way I want it. however is there a way to separate the employee ID's into separate cell as supposed to be all in the B column?

Comment: @Luke Please see the latest edited answer of my and refresh your screen if needed to see the latest. The name of the section I believe you are asking about it labeled **PowerShell (new variation)**. If this helps you solve, don't forget to turn the grey check mark to the top left of the answer green to show you accept it and to give me credit. If you need other trivial adjustments and I'll get to it as soon as I can to help you get a solution 100% for this questionn

Comment: Unfortunately not, It put all the data from the row into column A. If possible Im looking to achieve class in col A and instructor in col B - R(if needed)

Comment: @Luke Ah, there you go, I just had to swap the `[PSCustomObject]` item order around to get that expected output. Let me know how it goes with that one.

Comment: I tried the following 
 'Class' = ($_.group).'Class_Id' -join " ";
        'Instructor' = ($_.group).'Instructor' | Select-Object -Unique;
* not the order I need it exported in
'Instructor' = ($_.group).'Instructor' | Select-Object -Unique;
        'Class' = ($_.group).'Class_Id' -join " "; 
* Is the layout I need however all the Instructor (A numbers are lumped into one cell and would prefer to have them in there own separate cell in that row.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Luke .... Just now getting to this and able to adjust and test. Please refresh your screen again when you get a chance and see the newest version of **new variation** PowerShell logic. I turned the classes into `[PSCustomObject]` of `class1`, `class2`, ... `class5` and used the index values of the `($_.group)[0]`, `($_.group)[1]`, ... `($_.group)[4]` to scale those out that way which hopefully makes sense so you can adjust, scale up more, back more, etc. to fit your need. In any case, let's see if the third time is the charm (or is this fourth or fifth time now). Happy to continue to help!!

Comment: @Luke ... Also, are you saying the `A` values are instructors and the `B` and `M` values are the classes? If so, I can flip that around for you no problem if you have trouble adjusting that if even needed or important in your case. In any event, I am more than happy to continue to help you get this fully resolved so please do let me know how it goes and what further adjustments you might need to get your problem resolved 100%.

Comment: Thank you so much that last piece definitely helped. A few little edits and joined it to my existing script and I'm away. What would take me a good day or more now only takes 3 mins.